# make a exe to be downloaded through website

Tags: winforms, deployment, exe, web-deployment

We have a exe (executable) file link on our website which a user has to download.
BUt, in most of places exe downloading is blocked. IS there any other better way except sharing it as a zip file?

Answer (score 0):

[**The corporate standard for deployment is the MSI file**](https://serverfault.com/questions/11670/the-corporate-benefits-of-using-msi-files/274609#274609) (Windows Installer - check the link for details on the major advantages).

I am not sure how a direct download of an MSI in the last versions of browsers will behave since every new browser version tends to add new problems, but if you deliver an MSI file you will at least provide a product better suited for corporate deployment (so far as you follow best MSI practice).

Comment: MSI does entries in registry, and we dont want that.

Comment: In that case all I can think of is ActiveX deployment via CAB files - and that is quite restricted too on most boxes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751974(v=vs.85).aspx, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721964(v=ws.10).aspx. And obviously your application must work as an ActiveX component.